# how can I set input text value in child window that is called from parent window?

Tags: javascript

I want to set textbox value in child window.This value is passed from parent window.I am using HTML and Javascript.Thanks in advance.My code is as below.

in parent window

```
var newWindow = window.open('child.html');
newWindow.id = 1;
newWindow.init();
```

in child window

```
function init(){
document.getElementById('id').value = id;
}
```

I think my code does not call to init() function.
I have tried

```
window.open('child.html').document.getElementById('id').value += 1;
```

in my parent window and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the page to actually load in the child:

```
var newWindow = window.open('child.html');
newWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    newWindow.id = 1;
    newWindow.init();
});
```

Depending on the `script` tag used to load `init`, you may need to be a bit more defensive:

```
var newWindow = window.open('child.html');
newWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    tryInit();
    function tryInit() {
        if (!newWindow.init) {
            setTimeout(tryInit, 10);
            return;
        }
        newWindow.id = 1;
        newWindow.init();
    }
});
```

You might have that give up after (say) 20 seconds so it's not constantly looping if something goes wrong.